# MapWithStateRDDRecord with kryo

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, kryo

How can I register `MapWithStateRDDRecord` in kryo?

When I'm trying to do.

```
`sparkConfiguration.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDD))`
```

I get an error

```
class MapWithStateRDDRecord in package rdd cannot be accessed in package org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd
[error]       classOf[org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDDRecord]
```

I'd like to make sure that all serialization is done via kryo thus I set `SparkConf().set("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "true")`. With this setting enabled I get exceptions during runtime. `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (Class is not registered: org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDDRecord)`

Comment: Why do you need to register it at all?

Comment: I'd like to make sure that all serialization is done via kryo thus I set ("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "true"). With this setting enabled I get exceptions during runtime. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (Class is not registered: org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDDRecord)

Comment: That is redundant. If you select Kryo as your default serializer, Spark will use that. Try register classes explicitly via `SparkConf.registerKryoClasses` without specifying `registrationRequired`

Comment: This is what I'm actually doing in my code but I get compilation error `class MapWithStateRDDRecord in package rdd cannot be accessed...` as in the question.

Comment: You're using `registrationRequired`, don't do that. Once you invoke `registerKryoClasses`, spark will automatically choose `Kryo` as the default serializer.

Comment: So, what is the actual meaning of registrationRequired and why should I don't do that?

Comment: *Whether to require registration with Kryo. If set to 'true', Kryo will throw an exception if an unregistered class is serialized. If set to false (the default), Kryo will write unregistered class names along with each object. Writing class names can cause significant performance overhead, so enabling this option can enforce strictly that a user has not omitted classes from registration.* The configuration equivalent of setting Kryo is `spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer`.

Comment: From this comment I understand that with registrationRequired I make sure that Spark will not loose performance due to unregistered classes.
With default setting I'll not get exception but I may loose performance.

Comment: From production use of `mapWithState` I can tell you this overhead is insignificant. Serializing your entire state via checkpoint outweighs that by orders of magnitude.