# How do I get a list of all unregistered classes for Kryo serialization?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, kryo

How to get all unregistered list of classes used, because say I have a spark job and I am getting `this class is not registered` exception only on runtime, and these classes are the internal classes which are accessible say `"org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDDRecord"`, this type of class pops up every time and even though I register it does not get registered.
Also, the custom classes which I made, how do I get all of them, say I have `Person` classes, I need to register two times. i.e. `Person` also `Array[Person]` because they are used in two different ways.

Registering like this below isn't working :

`Class.forName("org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDDRecord")`

Comment: saw your otherpost as well,MapWithStateRDDRecord you need to  register this class ,conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[Person],classOf[String]),classOf(MapWithStateRDDRecord))

Comment: classOf(MapWithStateRDDRecord) , `MapWithStateRDDRecord` is not accessible @tarun

Comment: Not even using like this ? .registerKryoClasses(
      Array(classOf[Person],classOf[Array[Person]])
    )

Comment: yes@tarun, but about `MapWithStateRDDRecord`, how do I register it?

Comment: @tarun,  .registerKryoClasses( Array(classOf[Person],classOf[Array[Person]]) )  is working fine

Comment: Note sure if this is of help to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555183/mapwithstaterddrecord-with-kryo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203301/discussion-between-tarun-and-phineas).